# String.Replace throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value must be positive

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-standard-2.1

I have the following code which throws an interesting exception:

```cs
string QueryText = "unknown input"; // This is a property

async Task MethodOneAsync() {
  // some async code here

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QueryText)) 
  {
    MethodTwo();
  }
}

void MethodTwo() {
  // some code

  MethodThree();

  // some more code
}

void MethodThree() {
  string replacedText = QueryText.Replace(",", ""); // this throws the exception
}
```

In the method three, there is a thrown exception:
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value must be positive. Parameter name: count`

The exact stack trace of the exception is:

```
StringBuilder.Append (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 count)
String.ReplaceCore (System.String oldValue, System.String newValue, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Globalization.CompareOptions options)
String.Replace (System.String oldValue, System.String newValue, System.StringComparison comparisonType)
```

**Build and system info**

The project is built for Xamarin on .NET Standard 2.1.
We have only one crash reported for this issue, which happened on Android 13, but that shouldn't have anything to do with this.

I tried to write a test function in the same project to test a few inputs and see if it ever crashes.

```cs
static void Test(string text)
{
    text.Replace(",", "");
}
```

I then tested with the following inputs:

```cs
Test("");
Test(" ");
Test(null); // throws null reference exception
```

None of these threw the expected exception.

I then found an blog post: https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/632362-string-lastindexof-am-i-retarded which also happened on .NET Standard 2.0, and found some discussion about talking with threads and that it could happen in async.

So I have tried that with the following:

```cs
Task.Run(() => Test(" "));
Task.Run(() => Test(""));
Task.Run(() => Test("A"));
Task.Run(() => Test("B"));
Task.Run(() => Test("C"));
Task.Run(() => Test("D"));
Task.Run(() => Test("E"));
Task.Run(() => Test("F"));
Task.Run(() => Test("G"));
Task.Run(() => Test(","));
Task.Run(() => Test(" ,"));
Task.Run(() => Test(", "));
Task.Run(() => Test("a,"));
Task.Run(() => Test("a ,"));
Task.Run(() => Test("a, "));
Task.Run(() => Test(",a"));
Task.Run(() => Test(" ,a"));
Task.Run(() => Test(", a"));
```

This also has no results.

So, how could I reproduce it, and why is that happening?

Comment: The overload of `string.Replace` that takes 2 strings does not throw the exception you are seeing here. Also your stack track suggests the error is something to do with a `StringBuilder` which you haven't included here.

Comment: @DavidG obviously, I haven't included a system code here. It's a System namespace Assembly netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0.

Comment: The stacktrace looks like it's coming from the internal details of `Replace`, which uses `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Can you check: 1. if that happens on any input that lacks the to-be-replaced char? 2. If that does _not_ happen on inputs that contain the to-be-replaced char?

Comment: @Fildor thanks for reminding me, I haven't actually tested it with the to-be-replaced character. I extended my test with the following haystacks: `"," " ," ", " "a," "a ," "a, " ",a" " ,a" ", a"`. Neither of them did anything wrong, perhaps the input is not really the issue, but something to do with the threading as one of the external question suggested.

Comment: Edit worth mentioning here, I noticed that I check before calling all those methods to ensure the input is not null or empty.

Comment: I believe Xamarin on Android uses Mono (the Linux implementation of .NET). If so then it looks like a bug in the Mono implementation of `String.Replace` or in one of the underlying classes/methods that it uses. This can then only be fixed by upgrading to a newer Mono version if it exists, or else reporting a bug in Mono and hoping/helping for it to be fixed.

Comment: ^^ and to work around meanwhile.

Comment: I'm still concerned that you aren't showing us the relevant code. The stack trace says you are using a different overload of `Replace`, one that uses `string, string, StringComparison`. So all of your examples above are essentially pointless.

Comment: Also a note:  `.NET Standard` (any version) is *not* an implementation, it is just a collection of defined interfaces (classes and methods) that the implementing framework has to follow. So you never "run on" .NET Standard, you run on a framework that promises to implement it, which in this case would be Mono.

Comment: @DavidG The docs tell us: _This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue._ So obviously they call the overload with the StringComparison with the appropriate value to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @Steve Sure perhaps, but then the original overload should still be in the stack trace.